# Backbone.js not updating HTML in View

Tags: backbone.js

I have the view:

```
class FoursquareSearch.Views.SearchNew extends Backbone.View

  tagName: 'sidebar'

  template: JST["templates/search/new_search"]

  #events:
  #  'submit': 'create'

  initialize: ->
    @render

  render: ->
    console.log('hello')
    $this = $('#sidebar')
    $this.html('<p>All new content. <em>You bet!</em></p>')
    $this
```

with this Router

```
class FoursquareSearch.Routers.Maps extends Backbone.Router

  routes:
    '': 'index'

  index: ->
    FoursquareSearch.Views.maps = new FoursquareSearch.Views.Maps()
    @model = new FoursquareSearch.Models.Map()
    #originForm = new Traveltime.Views.ShapesOriginForm(model: model, map: Traveltime.Views.map)
    newSearch = new FoursquareSearch.Views.SearchNew(model: model, map: FoursquareSearch.Views.maps)
```

And this HTML

```
  <div id="top"></div>  
  <div id="sidebar">

  </div>
```

Init code:

```
window.FoursquareSearch =
  Models: {}
  Collections: {}
  Views: {}
  Routers: {}
  init: -> 

    new FoursquareSearch.Routers.Maps()
    Backbone.history.start()

$(document).ready ->
  FoursquareSearch.init()
```

I can see the `console.log` message however the HTML class / id does not get updated!

If I run:

```
$this = $('#sidebar')
$this.html('<p>All new content. <em>You bet!</em></p>')
```

in console I can see the HTML change on the page, it just seems that Backbone.js does not want to update the view for me?

Comment: Please add your initialization code.  Did you simply forget to call `Backbone.history.start()`?  Can you confirm via logging that `index` is actually called?

Comment: i have added the init code, not sure how i can confirm if index in actually called? but it does run the console.log as i said so i know its getting through to the render function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update @render to be @render() in your initialize method.  You are simply returning the method, but never calling it.

Comment: Thanks - however If i change that it makes no difference, in the example @muistooshort posted there is a FoursquareSearch.init()​​ at the end of the Router? If I add this i get a 'Error: Parse error on line 12: Unexpected 'IDENTIFIER''

Comment: @CharlieDavies: jsfiddle wraps everything in an onload handler so it doesn't need the `$(document).ready(...)` stuff. What is different between what you're doing and what my fiddle is doing?

Comment: i cant see any difference at all... its really odd!